# Elasticsearch postings highlighter returns too many sentences

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a problem with the postings highlighter. According to the docs: 
"...the postings highlighter... outputs sentences regardless of their length."

So, by setting:
`"number_of_fragments" : 1`
I should only get one sentence back. This is what happens 90% of the times but sometimes I get a really long text which is obviously more than 1 sentence. For example: (the highlighted words are **river** and **polluted**)

> It is a collegiate body with an advisory and deliberative of the Integrated Water Resources Management - working on Unit Water Resources Management 10, built by the state, municipalities and civil society, equally. [ 2 ] This committee took the initiative of civil society and currently includes 34 municipalities, 18 were located in Sorocaba **River** basin and 16 situated in the sub-basin of the upper Middle Tietê. [ 3 ] It has been a very **polluted river** due to industrial activities, mining, sewage without treatment, etc.

There are 3 sentences and the first two don't even have the highlighted words in them.
I think there is a bug here making the postings highlighter ignore '.' when followed by a '[' . I've noticed this to be the case in all bad highlighting results.

Is this a known bug? or am I missing something?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure whether I think it's a bug, per se.  Sentence boundaries aren't as simple as just splitting a periods (you don't want to break up "3.14" or "Mr. Smith"), and are often ambiguous.

`PostingsHighlighter` uses `java.text.BreakIterator` to detect where to break up sentences.  I had thought BreakIterator's behavior was based on [UAX #29](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Sentence_Boundaries), but this behavior isn't quite consistent with that ([you can try it here](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/breaks.jsp)).

So, it's possible it's a bug in java.text.BreakIterator, or that may just be the way their algorithm is intended to work.